# How to recover access to funds with blockchain.info passphrase

Tags: wallet, blockchain.info, wallet-recovery

Now at blockchain.info wallet I did backup my pass phrase. But I have no idea what my private key(s) are. There is no export that I can find. I understand there used to be.

[image]

If blockchain.info goes out of business, can I use my pass phrase to gain access to my funds from another wallet?

Comment: Can you clarify the part where you say there's no export option? (Screenshot, ideally)

Comment: @WizardOfOzzie, done. personal info cut out. There is no export functionality any more in blockchain.info

Comment: Oh of course. I'd forgotten the v2 wallet was the default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes, I can access my funds using only my pass phrase.

Mycelium, for example, when installed, comes up and asks if I want to restore a wallet from a 12-word passphrase, which is what blockchain.info created.

It then found my funds and will allow me to send / receive.

I have since learned that the pass phrase is just used to generate the private key using the SHA-256 hash algorithm.

Comment: The passphrase is actually used as the salt in `hmac-sha512` (BIP39)

Comment: @WizardOfOzzie, I'll research that and correct my answer. Thanks!